# How do I find the start and end line number of a selection in QTextEdit cursor?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a QTextEdit widget which is showing lines of text. I want the user to be able to select a block of text to be acted on.  I need to determine the starting and ending line numbers from the complete text that correspond to the selected block.

`editor.textCursor().blockNumber()`  gives me the correct starting line number but I haven't been able to find the line number of the ending postion.

Finding the length of the selection in lines would be fine.

I'm using PySide and Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`QTextCursor::selectionStart`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#selectionStart) and [`QTextCursor::selectionEnd`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#selectionEnd) to get block start and end position (as an `int`).

Then get copy of the text cursor, use [`QTextCursor::setPosition`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#setPosition) to set position to these two, and use [`QTextCursor::blockNumber`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#blockNumber) to get the line numbers.

There may be a shorter way, considering how `QTextCursor` has quite a lot of methods, but this should work. You may want to write a helper method, for example one which takes the position and a `QTextDocument` or `QTextCursor`, and returns the line number for that position.